# What weights mean in WeightIt package

Tags: r, matching, weightit

I want to balance my data using the WeightIt package in R (`method= ebal`). I have used a code similar to the one below;

#Balancing covariates between treatment groups (binary)

```
W1 <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + married + nodegree + re74, data = lalonde, method = "ebal", estimand = "ATT")

match.data(W1)
```

The outcome is my data table with an additional column called `weights`. What do those weights mean and how do I go on from here? (My next step would be to do a logit regression with a balanced dataset)

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

`weightit()` estimates weights that, when applied to a dataset, yield balance in the treatment groups. To estimate effects in the weighted sample, include the weights in a regression of the outcome on the treatment. This is demonstrated in the [WeightIt vignette](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/WeightIt.html).

You should not used `match.data()` with `WeightIt`. I'm not sure where you found the code to do that. `match.data()` is for use with `MatchIt`, which is a different package with its own functions. The fact that `match.data()` happened to work with `WeightIt` is unintended behavior and should not be relied on.

To estimate the effect of the treatment on a binary outcome (which I'll denote as `Y` in the code below and assume is in the `lalonde` dataset, even though in reality it is not), you would run the following after running the first line in your code above:

```
fit <- glm(Y ~ treat, data = lalonde, weights = W1$weights, family = binomial)
lmtest::coeftest(fit, vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC)
```

The coefficient on `treat` is the log odds ratio of the outcome.